# How to modify the Content in RuleAction

Tags: c#

Below is the code I have written. I need to modify the content which is available in rr

for example :

```
 if rr.ThenAction = "this.MacroLoop.Current.Strategy.SubStrategy.Current.Block.AIN.HLOP = 0"
```

I need it to be modified to

```
   "rr.ThenAction = "this.MacroLoop.Current.Strategy.SubStrategy.Current.Block.AIN.HLOP = 1"

if (!ruleSet.Validate(rv))
{ 
List<System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.Rule> rulesList = new List<System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.Rule>(); 
rulesList = ruleSet.Rules.ToList();
foreach (System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.Rule rr in rulesList) 
{ 
    // I need to modify the content in rr



} 
}
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: do you need to check for each rr in loop ?

Comment: Each rr needs to be modified. But the content will change

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but are you looking for something like;

```
 rulesList = ruleSet.Rules.ToList();
 for (int i = 0; i < rulesList.Count; i++)
        {
            rulesList[i] = "sddfs";
            if(rulesList[i].ThenAction == "this.MacroLoop.Current.Strategy.SubStrategy.Current.Block.AIN.HLOP = 0")
                {
                        rulesList[i].ThenAction = "this.MacroLoop.Current.Strategy.SubStrategy.Current.Block.AIN.HLOP = 1";
                }
        }
```

Hope it helps...!!!

PS: if you are planning to change value of rr in foreach, then it will not work as foreach is a read only iterator that iterates dynamically classes that implement IEnumerable, but you can use item.value to make changes.

Comment: I am getting error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.RuleAction' and 'string' "

Comment: In that case you have to create temp RuleAction have the value you want to compare and also one for what you want to assing